# Sql: have a column return 1 or 0 denoting if an id exists in a table for a predetermined groupID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wrote the following SQL to create a column that I can use to populate check boxes in a Grid to manage user permissions.

```
SELECT access_b2b.access_id,
       access_b2b.description,
       'active'= CASE
                   WHEN access_group.group_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END
FROM   access_b2b
       LEFT JOIN access_group
              ON access_group.access_id = access_b2b.access_id
WHERE  ( access_group.group_id = 10
          OR access_group.group_id IS NULL )
```

However, it does not select all of the entries from `access_b2b`. The issues is with the last line:

`where (access_group.group_id=10 or access_group.group_id is null)`

Without it, i get duplicate entries returned with different `active` values. Also, I realized that this is not the proper condition, because an entry in `access_group` might exist for a different `access_group.group_id`, meaning that not all the remaining entries will be pulled in with the `access_group.group_id is null`.

I am trying to write my condition so that if does something along the lines of:

This is the format I was trying to follow:

```
Where For Each unique access_id in access_group
    select the one where group_id=10
    if no group_id=10
        select any other one
    end
end
```

**Ultimately, the goal is to have a column returned with 1 or 0 denoting if the access_id exists for a predetermined group id.**

Please note that throughout this explanation I used group_id=10 for simplification, it will be later replaced with a SqlParameter.

Any help is appreciated, thank you so much!

SAMPLE DATA (only useful columns shown to simplify data)

```
access_group            
access_id group_id 
27          1
27          11
28          1
28          11
33          1
33          3
33          11
43          11
44          1
44          10
44          11
...

 access_b2b
access_id description
1          Add
2          Edit
3          Delete
4          List
5          Payments
6          Open Files
7          Order
8          Mod
...
```

Comment: Could you please give some (fake) sample data? I have a hard time visualizing your table.

Comment: sure @BasR. give me a few minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the query to and it should work:

```
SELECT access_b2b.access_id,
       access_b2b.description,
       'active'= CASE
                   WHEN access_group.group_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END
FROM   access_b2b
       LEFT JOIN access_group
              ON access_group.access_id = access_b2b.access_id
                  AND ( access_group.group_id = 10
          OR access_group.group_id IS NULL )
```

If you don't want the records to be filtered by the WHERE clause, move the condition in the JOIN.

The `JOIN` will keep the lines and populate them with `NULL` if the condition is not met, while the `WHERE` clause will filter the result set.

Comment: Brilliant! That makes sense, I was trying to filter after they were joined, that was my issue! Thank you!

Comment: @starvator You're welcome. It always helps to know/remember how the order of execution of the statements of a query is.